# Python Eve, SQLalchemy and ForeignKey

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, eve

I am working in a *Python Eve* based RESTful service with a *SQLAlcemy* backend. I have two models with a one to many relationship:

```
class User(CommonColumns):

    """Model of an user in the database"""
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String, unique=True)
    email = Column(EmailType, unique=True)
    folders = relationship('Folder', backref='user')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username


class Folder(CommonColumns):

    """Model of an user in the database"""
    __tablename__ = "folder"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{}/{}".format(self.user.username, self.name)
```

`CommonColumns`is defined like [here](http://eve-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html)

This works great when inserting, updating and deleting `users`. However, I can't get inserting right for `folders`:

```
newfolder = {
'name':'FOLDER',
 'user_id': 1,
}
response = requests.post("http://localhost:8080/api/v1.0/folders",data=newfolder)
print response.json()

{u'_error': {u'code': 422,
  u'message': u'Insertion failure: 1 document(s) contain(s) error(s)'},
 u'_issues': {u'exception': u"'user'"},
 u'_status': u'ERR'}
```

Which is a rather cryptic error message. I've been reading *Python Eve*'s documentation and I can't really understand what I am doing wrong. The only difference I see between `user` and `folder` insertions is that one has foreign keys.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it seemed that the problem was that **I didn't have the same name for the resource and the table name** ("users" for resource, "user" for table name). This seems to raise problems with foreign keys in eve, but does not fail with entities without relationships.

Changing the table names to match the resource names solved the problem.

I hope this will be useful to anyone.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your solution... I am in a similar situation. Table B has a foreign key in Table A. Inserting in Table A (parent) is okay but while trying to insert into table B throws error `"cpa_id": "unknown field"`